# How can I set the style of the Tk object in Tkinter (main window)?

Tags: tkinter, styles, tk-toolkit

In Tkinter it is possible to change the style by setting the arguments
bg and fg, it is true for almost all the widgets, but I have an error when I tried to do the same in the Tk object.

```
text = Text(root,fg='blue' bg='black')#work
root = Tk(,fg='blue' bg='black')#ERROR
```

How can I set the style of the Tk object (main window)

Comment: Something like `root['bg'] = 'black'` should work

Comment: You can't set the root window options via it's constructor. You have to either do it via `configure` or directly using a key, like the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some problems with `root = Tk(fg='blue' bg='black')`, because it will caused `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fg'`and I think there shouldn't have a foreground color for the main window.

But I successed with this.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root['bg'] = 'black'
root.mainloop()
```